# New SSD Causing Kernel Panic

Tags: mac

Before you write this off as just another replacement SSD kernel panics, I've tried safe mode, reformatting, new OS, older macOS versions, resetting SMC and all the other stuff.

So I have the mid 2012 unibody 13 inch MBP, and decided to install a new 240gb PNY SSD into it. For 2-3 months it worked great, on Catalina, and then started to kernel panic often, with seemingly random apps causing it, and even kernel_task. I decided to reset the SMC, pram and nvram, but still nothing changed.

Then I decided to go back to Mojave, and the same issue occured, even with a clean install and barely any apps installed.

I heard things about hardware solutions and broken cables, should I try plugging in the old HDD and see if that fixes the issue, or what should I do???

Comment: I'd put the old one back in and try that. If the problem doesn't occur, then it's a hardware fault with the new SSD.

Comment: This question seems a bit odd - why do you think the new SSD is the cause of the problem? - You have included nothing in the question to support that assumption. Could you include the contents of the actual kernel panics and a description of what you have done to diagnose the problem that makes you certain it is the SSD?

Comment: Other than providing more information about what your kernel panic logs are showing, you could try running macOS off an external hard drive. If you immediately get kernel panics after booting off an external hard drive, it's very possible other components have gone faulty and not the SSD.